# "There has been a critical error on your website" error on first loading but ok after refreshing

Tags: wordpress

I have encountered a problem after hosting my site on server. It is working good in my local server. Sometimes it works good but suddenly it is displaying "**There has been a critical error on your website**" and the main thing is- it occurs at first loading. After refreshing it displays the original content of my website.

I have already made the **wp_debug= true** but it didn't help and it was displaying white/blank page.

Thanks in advance for any kind of suggestions